# cant access to store in redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i want to use redux in my react native app 
and i make my reducer correctly (i think ) and after that create store and then use dispatch or store but i get error actually i cant use dispatch

my app.js:

```
   const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));
export default class taav extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Chatroom />
        </Provider>
    );
}
}
```

and my chatroom :

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {Text, Button, TabBarIOS, View} from 'react-native'
 import MessageList from './messageList'
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    testtest: state.chatroom.teststore.test
}
 }

   export const Testredux = connect(mapStateToProps)(MessageList)


      export default class Chatroom extends Component {
   state = {
    test2: "dfsd"
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this')
}

btn() {


    dispatch({type: 'test1'})////////////this is wrong???
}

render() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Testredux test={'sdfdsf'}/>
            <Button title={'sdfsdf'} onPress={this.btn.bind(this)}/>
        </View>  )


}


 }
```

do you know why i cant use dispatch????

Answer (score 1):

You have not imported the 'dispatch' function anywhere so that's why you can't use it. You would have to import your store and then call store.dispatch().

However, the best (and recommended) way would be to use **mapDispatchToProps** with the **connect** function from react-redux when you export your **Chatroom** component:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        sendTestAction: () => { dispatch({type: 'test1'}) }
    })
}
```

...and then use it with **connect** like this when you export your component:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Chatroom)
```

In your **Chatroom** component you can then do:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Testredux test={ 'sdfdsf' }/>
            <Button title={ 'sdfsdf' } onPress={ this.props.sendTestAction }/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting the wrong class

```
export const Testredux = connect(mapStateToProps)(MessageList)
```

should be

```
export const Testredux = connect(mapStateToProps)(Chatroom)
```

Comment: no i want to connect that things to messageList @hairmot

Comment: as it is,, your Chatroom component is not connected to the store. You connect a component by passing it into the connect function. If you aren't connected to the store, you can't dispatch actions.

Comment: it means that i can just dispatch from the component which i connected already??? maybe i want dispatch sth from one component that i never connected yet but actually, i thought i  can access to store and dispatch at whatever i want because i send store by a provider .@hairmot

Comment: and just now i try dispatch from my messageList component which i connected already but it said dispatch is not defined @hairmot

Comment: i suggest you do some reading on how connect works http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/ if you need to pass functionality from one component to another, consider passing it down as props

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` is a prop passed to the component wrapped in the `connect` call. Since you're wrapping `MessageList` instead of `Chatroom`, instances of `Chatroom` cannot access any props passed by Redux.

Additionally, `dispatch` should be accessed as a prop, so it should be `this.props.dispatch` instead of just `dispatch`:

```
btn() {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'test1'})
}
```